# SQLite query to return only countries in Europe

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

Not sure how to best phrase this for google. But I've got a SQLite table that has about 120k rows and one of the columns is full country name. Unfortunately the data source doesn't group things by region and I want to return only those full country names that are in Europe. Is there something that exists that I can do my select or group by from?

Also this is originally a .xlsx file that I convert to CSV then import into DB Browser. When I imported it, it didn't ask for headers (or treat the top row as headers). Is there a way to set that?

Comment: You can create a list of all countries in EU and after it makes a query. Yes, you can add header in existing file

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to hard-code the countries in your `SELECT` clause but to add a second table that does provide such a region grouping. The reason is simply: countries within a region can change quite fast.

With such a second table you can simply query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    table_name t
    JOIN countries c ON c.Id = t.CountryID
WHERE
    c.Region = 'EUROPE'
```

Yes, creating such a second table is work but it's definitely worth it!

Answer (score 0):

To get those records where the country is in Europe, the only way I see this being done is to use an `in` clause followed by all European countries. Example with just a few countries:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE County in ('GERMANY', 'FRANCE', 'SPAIN', 'ENGLAND');
```

I have found a list of European countries [here.](https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/countries-of-europe.html)

Comment: That list could be out of date in a couple of years (at least as far as the EU is concerned :-) ) A linked table would be better.